# what are the pros and cons of setting virtual host in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using multiple domains to access liferay portal instance.

For example following are the domains mapped in hosts file of windows:

1. `www.liferaytest1.com`
2. `www.liferaytest2.com`

and in Liferay's <kbd>Control Panel</kbd> → <kbd>Portal Settings</kbd>, `www.liferaytest1.com` is set as virtual host.

I can access portal instance with all above mention domains along with `localhost`.

When I access portal with `www.liferaytest1.com` then I can access `Guest` site pages directly. Say, `home` is a page in `Guest` site then instead of accessing with `www.liferatest1.com/web/guest/home` I can access it directly with `www.liferaytest1.com/home`

So URL is shortened to some extend.
So far so good.

#### First Concern

Now when I try to access portal via `www.liferaytest2.com` and when I click any sites listed in `My Sites` portlet of Liferay, it redirects me to that site with the domain mentioned in virtual host i.e. `www.liferaytest1.com` instead of retaining `www.liferaytest2.com`.

Suppose I have a Site named `Help`, so when I click on help site link in `My Sites` portlet then instead of staying with `www.liferaytest2.com` domain it redirects me with `www.liferaytest1.com` domain.

This is due to virtual host mapping done in liferay.

#### Second Concern

When I am accessing the portal with `www.liferaytest2.com` and subscribe to any of the Assets then the links in email contain the virtual host domain i.e `www.liferaytest1.com`.

---

***How to overcome above mention issues?***

My requirement is to stay relative to the portal accessing domain.
When I access portal via `www.liferaytest2.com` then it should not redirect me to `www.liferaytest1.com` on-click of any of the Site-links as explained above and also emails that I would be getting should also be relative to the domain I am accessing i.e. `www.liferaytest2.com`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You're not required to use that feature - it's implemented in a certain way (e.g. as you describe) and if that doesn't suit your needs, there's no need to configure individual virtual hosts. There's no problem serving all content through just a single virtual host or do the resolution on Apache (e.g.) - that is, fully external to Liferay. The only drawback is that you'll need the clue of the site you want to access (e.g. /web/guest as part of the URL) so that Liferay knows what content to serve.

However, you might be closer to what you'd like to achieve if you change URLs to a structure like `test1.example.com` and `test2.example.com` - this way you share at least the toplevel domain and might be able to do some cheaper single-sign-on (you can still do SSO with completely different domains)

Comment: I am concern about the email part. When I set localhost as virtual host then in liferay generated emails contains link with reference to localhost and when I set say www.liferaytest1.com as virtual host then it contains link with reference to www.liferaytest1.com. This is as per desired but when I access portal with www.liferaytest2.com and virtual host set to  www.liferaytest1.com then it is not desired to get emails with refence to www.liferaytest1.com. In such a case I want email links with reference to www.liferaytest2.com.
How to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the virtual host in Control Panel → Portal Setting for such requirement. Rather keep it to localhost. This will resolve both of your concerns.

Next you want to access portal using two different domain, you can do it through DNS settings. Map both to same IP (the IP of Liferay portal) and you will reach Liferay portal using any one. It will not change the url and will stay from the name initiated.